# Find first occurrence from the end with awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

Is is possible to find first string occurrence from the end of file using `awk` or `sed`? Or I will need to use some scripting language like Python or Perl?

Comment: Please post sample Input_file and expected output in code tags into your post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Any email message in EML format which was forwarded multiple times. I want to extract original message. It came up that first `Return-Path:` from the bottom of EML file indicates that original message.

Comment: If you could give a sample example(you could hide actual things off course) it will be good for us to understand requirements please.

Comment: Forgive me, I found it easier to answer than to search for the duplicate. :) But yeah, this is definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can revert the order of lines in the file with `tac` (the opposite of `cat`) and then use `grep`:

```
tac file | grep -m 1 STRING
```

`grep -m1` gives you only the first occurrence.

Alternatively you may just pipe `grep` to `tail`:

```
grep STRING | tail -n1
```

---

If you want to use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{res=""}/STRING/{res=$0}END{if(res!=""){print res}}' file
```

Explanation:

```
# Initialize result with an empty string
BEGIN{res=""}
# If STRING is found, store the current line in res.
# This will overwrite a previous result, giving you
# always only the last occurrence.
/STRING/{res=$0}
# Once the end of input has been reached print the result
# if STRING was found.
END{if(res!=""){print res}}
```

Comment: Perfect examples!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: I have ended up with that code `tac $file | sed -n '1,/^Return-Path:/p;' | sed -ne "/^--$wrapping_boundary/d;p" | tac > out/$file`

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed`

```
sed -n '/string/h;${x;p}' infile
```

Using awk

```
tac infile | awk '/abc/{print;exit}'
```

Test Results:

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat infile
abc 1
xyz 2
pwd 3
cwd 4
aks 5
axy 6
abc 7
xyz 8
nwd 9

akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ sed -n '/abc/h;${x;p}' infile
abc 7

akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ tac infile | awk '/abc/{print;exit}' 
abc 7
```

Comment: Just in my defense, I haven't copied the `awk` solution from here please, seems to be our timings were almost same :)

Answer (score 3):

Following `tac` and `awk` combination will help you to read the very first occurrence of any string very quickly.

```
tac Input_file | awk '/STRING/{print;exit}'
```

***Explanation:*** `tac` will reverse the Input_file then `awk` will check for the string and as soon as it gets it will print the line and exit from it, since are only bothered about very first occurrence so no need to read whole Input_file here.